# error with using statement

Tags: c#, using

while the  use of  Using statement  receive this error

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

And While Use  Without Using Not receive  error
What is the reason for this error?

```
using (var context = new ProCamContext())
{
    var q = context.CatCamera.Where(p => p.Category.Equals(value)).Select(p => p.CatDetails);
    return Json(q);
}
```

Comment: `return Json(q.ToList())` should work

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is no doubt due to *deferred execution*.

Forcing that query to evaluate *should* work, by calling a method that forces it to make a trip to the database. `ToList` should be enough:

```
var q = context.CatCamera
    .Where(p => p.Category.Equals(value))
    .Select(p => p.CatDetails).ToList();
```

Currently, by the time your query is evaluated, your context will be disposed of and cannot call into the database. Hence the error.

Comment: If the function `Json` forces a `IQueryable` to be passed in instead of an `IEnumerable` and it can not be modified you can "hack" around it by doing `.ToList().AsQueryable()`

Answer (score 1):

Your context has been disposed prior to the query being executed.  `return Json(q)` is returning the query expression without executing it first.  Try calling ToList() to actually run the query before exiting the using scope.

```
using (var context = new ProCamContext())
{
    var q = context.CatCamera.Where(p => p.Category.Equals(value)).Select(p => p.CatDetails).ToList();
    return Json(q);
}
```